# Could not understand Sagemaker code in logistic regression model

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I started working on sagemaker recently and I'm trying to understand what each line of code does in sagemaker examples. 
I'm stuck at following code. I'm working on logistic regression of bank data.

```
from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri
```

Can anyone explain the what get_image_uri does?
  Also can anyone share a link or something where each line of code related to sagemaker is explained.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model.html

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately I can't do much better than the [source code](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/52c74752561d3dae9f8d5730312403d5aaff651c/src/sagemaker/amazon/amazon_estimator.py#L525-L545), which says:

> Return algorithm image URI for the given AWS region, repository name, and repository version

the link by [PV8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model.html) has demo code, but it's basically getting a HTTPS URL  that points to a ["disk drive" image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) that is then used by AWS to spin up a new [EC2 container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) with [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) configured and running

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SageMaker is designed to be open and extensible, and it is using Docker images as the way to communicate between the development (notebooks), training and tuning, and finally hosting for real-time and batch prediction.

When you want to submit a training job, for example, you need to point the docker image that is holding the algorithm and pre/post-processing code that you want to execute as part of your training.

Amazon SageMaker is providing a set of built-in algorithms that you can use out of the box to train models in scale (mostly optimized for distributed training). These algorithms are identified by their name, and the above line of python code is mapping between the name and the URI of the docker image that Amazon provided in the container registry service - ECR.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of a deprecation in the latest version of Amazon packages.

Just force the use of previous versions, by adding to the very beginning of the notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -qU awscli boto3 "sagemaker>=1.71.0,<2.0.0"
```

Now when loading the method you want:

```
from sagemaker.amazon.amazon_estimator import get_image_uri
```

you will just get a deprecation warning, but the code works fine anyway:

```
'get_image_uri' method will be deprecated in favor of 'ImageURIProvider' class in SageMaker Python SDK v2.
```

Cheers